# NextJS and Responsive Design

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, server-side-rendering, next.js

I have developed quite a big single page application using create-react-app.
I am in the process of migrating everything to NextJS, mainly for SEO purposes.
I'm scratching my head on one issue : what is the best way to handle responsive design?
In my create-react-app legacy code, I'm always keepings components in sync with window.innerWidth, and am using it to handle most of the responsiveness (except for the grid layout that is handled by material-ui).
But since we can't guess the client's width during the server render, then how can you avoid a 'flicker' of the UI?
Do we need to delay any responsive UI logic until we can execute on the client?

Comment: You may need to rewrite the responsive design using css mediaqueries https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp. Javascript should not be used to manage the responsive due to performance concern.

Comment: this makes total sense, thanks! my responsive design is a mix of a ui framework (material-ui), media queries (both css files, and aphrodite), and then some JS. I'll go over my code and clean everything.

Comment: yep.. better do it sooner than later. Reminding all the bad memories of my previous projects...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is :
using javascript to handle responsivness is bad practice, css should be used if we don't want to browser to re-flow the content on the screen.
if you are using material-ui, take a look at [this page](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-hidden/)

Comment: This isn't necessarily true.  There are use cases where conditionally rendering components can allow for a much smaller bundle size due to code splitting.

It's true that there are tradeoffs, but I wouldn't say it's bad practice (anymore).  

You just have to account several more things (like giving a value to screen/device width on the server based on the device type) and be aware of edge cases which can arise if not handling SSR correctly.

Comment: @JeremyHindle Conditionally rendering components is a good thing but I think people switch to SSR for a better SEO and if for the sake of conditional rendering your component is not rendered at all, this might hit the SEO. Also if you see the [withWidth](https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/#withwidth) HOC is going to be deprecated soon is favour of [useMediaQuery](https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/) to overcome what I just said again with conditional rendering. A better answer would be to choose **wisely** depending upon the need.

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 1):

This is how I tackled the problem I defined a theme and breakpoints for my stylings. in theme.js file I use createTheme from material-ui. it gives you the option of defining breakpoints:

```
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      xs: 0,
      sm: 600,
      md: 960,
      lg: 1220,
      xl: 1920,
    },
  }
```

I predefined sizes I want to change styles based on them. meaning that 0 to 600 is a mobile view...
this is how I use breakpoints in my styles classes

```
const styles = theme => {
  return {
 classname: {
    //css codes for web view
      [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
        //css codes for mobile view. 
      },
      [theme.breakpoints.between('sm', 'md')]: {
        //css codes tablet view
      },
      [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
       //css codes for resizes between web to tablet size
      },
    },
    }}
```

By resizing the window or opening the page in different devices you will see the different styles. It works fine in both ssr and client side components.

note:
If you are not interested in predefining the sizes you can use a different size for each css class like this one.

```
 [theme.breakpoints.down('600')]: {
        //css codes for mobile view. 
      },
```